# How can I pass processing square brackets with asciidoc?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

Asciidoctor properly renders following line.

```
some text [address[title]]
```

When I add a hard break like this,

```
some text +
[address[title]]
```

the second line is not rendered at all.

How can I solve this?

**update**

So far, I found that one leading space does the job. I'm not sure this is a desired effect.

```
some text +
 [address[title]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `[xxx]` on a new line is the syntax to defined a role for the next bloc.

When the Asciidoctor paser is confused, my solution is to define some variables on top of my document and to use them:

```
:opening-bracket: &#91;
:closing-bracket: &#93;

{opening-bracket}address{opening-bracket}title{closing-bracket}{closing-bracket}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's another trick - add a "dummy" hard break:

```
some text +
[address[title]] +
```